# Portably get one character from standard input using standard library only

Tags: c, strings, io

While translating an old Basic game to C, I found myself needing a function to get one character from the keyboard.  You can't do this with common standard C library functions like `getchar()` because the standard input stream is [line-buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36573506/2644192) (i.e. it will store whole line of input, including the terminating `\n`, in its internal buffer although `getchar()` only uses its first character. Subsequent calls to `getchar()` will consume buffer's remaining characters until exhausted and only then will it resume accepting user's new inputs).  This causes problems because if you need inputting twice, the second time you will get some unexpected value instead of letting user entering second character.

Now, I know the way around this is to use operating system calls such as [`ioctl`](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) and [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to set input to an unbuffered state and read a character (or better yet use a library like [`Curses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) which abstracts away all this in a cross-platform way.) but I started wondering if it was possible to do this entirely via the standard C library.

My first attempt was to empty out the remaining characters in `stdin`'s buffer by adding a call to:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

...after calling `getchar()` but this didn't do anything.

My next attempt was to try and take `stdin` out of line buffer mode like this:

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

I had high hopes this would work but actually it seems calling `setvbuf` on `stdin` is undefined behavior.  It certainly does not work on Linux.

So finally I came up with this function.  It works but I have a nagging feeling it could be improved.  What do you think?

```
int getkey(const char* prompt = "") {
    /* Print the prompt message if there is one */
    if (strcmp(prompt, "") != 0) {
        puts(prompt);
    }

    /* Get a character and examine it.  If it is a newline from a previous
       call to this function eat it otherwise put it back in the buffer. */
    int c = getchar();
    if (c != '\n') {
        ungetc(c, stdin);
    }

    /* This is the character we really want. */
    c = getchar();

    /* Drain the input buffer so any extra characters which were pressed are
       discarded except for newline which is needed to actually send the input 
       to stdin. */
    int next;
    while(!feof(stdin) && next != '\n') {  
        next = getchar();
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's valid C ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `strcmp` can be replaced with:

```
if (*prompt) {
```

Your last loop has issues. You effectively have both a precondition (`feof`) and a postcondition (`next`). You can replace the lot with:

```
while (!feof(stdin))
    if (getchar() == '\n')
        break;
```

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't mention the UB when `next` is used uninitialized...

Comment: Wait, next won't default initialize to 0?  Or am I thinking of C++ again?

Comment: @TobySpeight I would have mentioned it, but I decided to omit the variable entirely instead

Comment: @Jaldhar Why do you think `next` is initialized in C++?

Answer (score 2):

> if it was possible to do this entirely via the standard C library.

Yes, yet OP's code has issues.

**Invalid C**

Standard C does not have default function parameters.  Even if it did, as in C++, the usage belongs in a .h file *declaration*, not the .c file *definition*.

```
// int getkey(const char* prompt = "") {
int getkey(const char* prompt) {
```

**No need to involve `stdout` in a `stdin` function**

Consider dropping the prompt code.  If still desired, code as a higher level function.  Also allow a prompt without an output `'\n'` occurring.  Be prepared for `stdout` as fully buffered or unbuffered.

```
  int prompt_and_getkey(const char* prompt) {
    // Do not use puts() which appends a \n, let caller decide.
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);  // Ensure output occurs before input.

    return getkey();
  }
```

**Bug**

Below code uses `next` before it is assigned, thus **undefined behavior** (UB) and anything may happen.  This also implies that OP does not have all warnings enabled with a good compiler as such trivial errors are automatically detected.  Save time.  Enable all warnings.

```
int next;
while(!feof(stdin) && next != '\n') {    // bad code
```

**Handle rare input error**

`feof(stdin)` is simply the wrong test as the below is an infinite loop on input error.  The earlier answers are also infinite loops on input error.

```
// bad
int next;
while(!feof(stdin) && next != '\n') {  
    next = getchar();
}

// Amended
int next = ch;
while(next != EOF && next != '\n') {  
    next = getchar();
}
```

**Questionable design**

Code does not consider that the input may be simple `"\n"`.  Code *assumes* a first read `'\n'` is due to a previous line.  Instead it may simple be a line that only consists of `"\n"`

To fix, code needs to re-architect the whole idea of leaving `'\n'` in `stdin` for the *next* line to read.  Better to have code finish consuming the line before calling code to get the next line.

**`fflush(stdin)` and `feof()`**

Calling these functions are often  strong indications of questionably-designed code.  I recommend to never use `fflush(stdin)` and then use `feof()` only once one is very clear on its need: to distinguish end-of-file from input error.  Do not use `feof()` to determine if end-of-file occurred.  Use `... == EOF` to determine if end-of-file or input error occurred.

**Unclear comments**

Example: "Drain the input buffer so any extra characters which were pressed are discarded **except** for newline".  The **except** does not apply here as code also discards `'\n'`.

**Simplification**

Code only needs to check the first character.  Testing `*string_pointer` for an empty string test is idiomatic in C and is [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
// WET
// if (strcmp(prompt, "") != 0) {

// DRY
if (*prompt) {
```

Either source code may emit the same run-time code.  As with such style issue, consult your group's coding guide.

Answer (score 1):

First, *I'm not sure*, but default parameter [isn't valid in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472138/c-default-arguments)

Otherwise, you lack includes:

```
#include <stdio.h> //puts, getchar, printf
#include <string.h> //strcmp
```

You can get rig of `strcmp` call (and by extension, the `string.h` header):

```
if (prompt != NULL && *prompt) {...}
```

Finally, your loop can be simplified, removing useless (and unsafe) variable:

```
 while(!feof(stdin) && getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: Oops just noticed I've been compiling this program as C++ (which I normally use) not C.  The intent was to write C though.  Also:  @reinderien made a similar observation about the strcmp but he did not do an explicit NULL check.  Is that really necessary?

Comment: This is one function out of a larger program so I didn't bother showing the includes.  Of course they are there in the actual codebase.

Comment: For your first message, to make a long explanation short, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321459/what-is-the-difference-between-str-null-and-str0-0-in-c). Otherwise, for the 2nd point, since you have to provide a full working code, you have to provides includes.  Take care for the next :)

Comment: @Jaldhar It's not a bad idea, for robustness.